# Efficient way to calculate distance to value in matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, distance

I have an image and want to calculate for each non zero value pixel its distance to the closest zero value pixel.
The way i tried to do it is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from skimage import io

im=io.imread('imagepath')
#getting array where elements are 0
a,b = np.where(im == 0) 
# create a list with (row,column)
x = list(zip(a, b)) 
#getting array where elements are non zero
r, c =np.where(im!=0)
#create a list with (row, column) of all non 0 values
#note coordinates are in y, x format
obj = list(zip(r,c))
dist_dict={}
#calculating for each pixel of the object
for o in obj:    
    d = (cdist(np.array([o]), x, metric='euclidean')).min() 
    dist_dict.update({o:d})
```

I believe this should work, however it is quite slow. For a single pixel it takes around 0.2 seconds to compute the distance. With objects around 50.000 pixels big this therefore would take around three hours of computation time per image, which is just not feasible at all.
One problem which I can see here is that I just iterate through all non zero pixels. 
Is there a way to start the search not at the beginning of array but from the current coordinates, until a zero value was found? Or are there any other suggestions how to speed up this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html) which finds the closest background point (value 0) with the smallest Euclidean distance to input pixels.

```
from scipy import ndimage
import pprint

def nearest_zero(image):
    " Finds closest background (zero) element for each element in image "

    # Find closest zero elements in the inverted image (same as closest non-zero for image)
    edt = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(image, return_indices=False)

    # Create dictionary of indexes
    return {(r,c):edt[r][c] for r in range(image.shape[0]) for c in range(image.shape[1]) if image[r][c]}
```

**Example of Usage**

```
image = np.array(([0,50,75,15,0],
                  [2,0,111,10,15],
                  [0,112,25,110,115],
                  [0,10,110,115,0],
                  [15,12,115,0,0]))


d = nearest_zero(image)
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

print('Original Image')
print(image)

print('\nDictionary of Distances to closest background pixel for each non-background pixel')
pp.pprint(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

**Output**

```
Original Image
[[  0  50  75  15   0]
 [  2   0 111  10  15]
 [  0 112  25 110 115]
 [  0  10 110 115   0]
 [ 15  12 115   0   0]]

Dictionary of Distances to closest background pixel for each non-background pixel
[   ((0, 1), 1.0),
    ((0, 2), 1.4142135623730951),
    ((0, 3), 1.0),
    ((1, 0), 1.0),
    ((1, 2), 1.0),
    ((1, 3), 1.4142135623730951),
    ((1, 4), 1.0),
    ((2, 1), 1.0),
    ((2, 2), 1.4142135623730951),
    ((2, 3), 1.4142135623730951),
    ((2, 4), 1.0),
    ((3, 1), 1.0),
    ((3, 2), 1.4142135623730951),
    ((3, 3), 1.0),
    ((4, 0), 1.0),
    ((4, 1), 1.4142135623730951),
    ((4, 2), 1.0)]
```

**Performance Testing**

*Result: SciPy is ~100 times faster*

*Test Data Generation -- Random Image (size 250x250 = 62, 500 pixels)*

```
import random
size = 250
z = [random.randrange(0, 255) for r in range(size) for c in range(size)]
image = np.array(z).reshape(size, size)
```

*Number Zeros in test image*

```
print(np.count_nonzero(image==0))  # 62262
```

*timeit Using Method from Original Posting*

```
11.6 s ± 89.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
which is an average of 1.8e-04 seconds per non-zero point
```

*timeit Using SciPy Method*

```
119 ms ± 17.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
Which is an average of 1.9e-06
```

**Thus SciPy is ~100 times faster**